# Selecting an html radio button dynamically through javascript does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, radio-button

I want to select a radio button from javascript. I am using this simple html file to test the issue. The code below works correctly on firefox and chrome, however it does not work in IE (no version works). I would like to know why the supplied code does not work on IE, and how to select a radio button in IE?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function chooseOne()
        {
            var randomChoice = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);

            if(randomChoice == 0)
            {
                document.getElementById("test0").checked = true;
            }
            else if (randomChoice == 1)
            {
                document.getElementById("test1").checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("test2").checked = true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="radio" id="test0" name="test" value="a" /> A<br />
    <input type="radio" id="test1" name="test" value="b" /> B<br />
    <input type="radio" id="test2" name="test" value="c" /> C<br />
    <input type="button" name="click" value="CHOOSE" onclick="javascript:chooseOne()" />
</body>
```

Thanks in Advance,
Spi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should give all your radio buttons the same `name`, otherwise they will act as if they are independent buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="test" id="test0" value="a" /> A<br />
<input type="radio" name="test" id="test1" value="b" /> B<br />
<input type="radio" name="test" id="test2" value="c" /> C<br />
```

I'm guessing this is also the source of your problem. Further, once you do this, you only need to set one radio button's `checked` to `true`, that will automatically remove the selection from other buttons.

Comment: I did your change and in fact, i don't need to set the other radio buttons to checked=false. However, still nothing happens in IE.

Comment: It works for me on IE6. What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: I am trying on IE 8 and IE 7, when i press the button, nothing happens, no radio button is selected, while on firefox and chrome a random radio button is selected each time I press the button

Comment: That's indeed strange. If this is a local file, are you sure IE isn't blocking scripts or something like that? It happens to me on IE6 and I have to manually allow scripts.

Comment: OMG, you're right. It wasn't actually running the script. Sorry my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but possibly you have to tell IE that your onclick code is in javascript like this:

```
<input type="button" name="click" value="CHOOSE" onclick="javascript:chooseOne()" />
```

Comment: Also, be careful about using `Math.round(Math.random() * 2);`. Because of the rounding, this generates 0 and 2 with a 25% chance each, and 1 with a  50% chance. To get 0, 1 and 2 with an even chance, use: `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);`

Comment: Yeah you are right. However in my case its not a problem since i am using it just to test the selection of radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

One problem:
`var randomChoice = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);`

will always yield to 1